# Facing issue in calling fragment class from adapter class in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have to call a fragment class from baseAdapter class. I have created a method in main fragment class like this

```
public  void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Reply_ozoneFragment()).commit();

    }
```

> and calling this method in adapter class like this.

holder.bt_reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        fragment.switchContent();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

                 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new Reply_ozoneFragment());

                 fragmentTransaction.commit();


        /*Intent reintent = new Intent(context,Reply_ozoneFragment.class);

        //reintent.putExtra("userid", S);
        context.startActivity(reintent);
        */
    }
});
```

but this is not working properly and my app crashes every time. Please tell me what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: first tell us what the crash log says

Comment: @tyczj  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

remove  `fragment.switchContent();` from your adapter button onclick() method and change

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

to

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```